# Get request from controller in model - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my API I used "with" method to get parent's model relation and everything works fine.
I want to add an attribute in my relation and return it in my API but I should use request in my model.

Something like this :

Book.php

```
protected $appends = ['userState'];
public function getUserStateAttribute () {
   return User::find($request->id); //request not exists here currently
}
```

I have $request in my controller (api controller)

Controller.php

```
public function get(Request $request) {
   Post::with('books')->all();
}
```

I believe using static content to append in array of model is so easy but how about using request's based content ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can use `request()` helper :

```
public function getUserStateAttribute () {
   return User::find(request()->get('id'));
}
```

Sure this is not really MVC pattern, but it can work

Answer (score 0):

You want to take request as a parameter here:

```
public function getUserStateAttribute (Request $request) {
   return User::find($request->id);
}
```

That way you can access it in the function. You will just need to always pass the Request object whenever you call that function.

e.g. `$book->getUserStateAttribute($request);`

Alternatively, you could just pass the ID, that way you need not always pass a request, like so:

```
public function getUserStateAttribute ($id) {
   return User::find($id);
}
```

Which you would call like:

e.g. `$book->getUserStateAttribute($request->id);`